# Passing extra data to yii uploader

Tags: ajax, yii2, yii-extensions, yii2-advanced-app

Am creating a file uploader using the kartik uploader bu the problem is that it doesn't pass extra data

The form(view) code

```
 <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'case_description')->textArea();?>


    <?php   echo $form->field($evidence, 'path')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
                    'options' => ['accept' => '*','multiple' => true,'name'=>'images'],
                    'pluginOptions' => [
                 'browseIcon' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></i> ',
                    'showPreview' => true,
                    'showCaption' => true,
                    'showRemove' => true,
                    'showUpload' => true,

                    'browseLabel' =>  'Insert Evidence',
                   'uploadUrl' => Url::to(['cases/upload']),
                   'maxFileCount' => 10,
                'uploadExtraData' => [
                      'album_id' => "javascript: return $('#cases-case_description').val());",
                  ],
                ],              

]
);?>
```

The $evidence ,path is a table related to the models table

The controller that I have tested with (code)

```
public function actionUpload(){

$ann = empty($_POST['album_id']) ? '' : $_POST['album_id'];
var_dump($ann)

}
```

This returns null showing that the album_id is not passed to the controller and yet the $model->case_description is the field above the upload widget

The new controller

```
public function actionUpload(){

$images = $_FILES['evidence'];
$success = null;

$paths= ['uploads'];

// get file names
$filenames = $images['name'];


// loop and process files
for($i=0; $i < count($filenames); $i++){
    //$ext = explode('.', basename($filenames[$i]));
    $target = "uploads/cases/evidence".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . md5(uniqid()); //. "." . array_pop($ext);
    if(move_uploaded_file($images['name'], $target)) {
        $success = true;
        $paths[] = $target;
    } else {
        $success = false;

        break;
    }

    echo $success;
}
    // check and process based on successful status 
if ($success === true) {


    $output = [];
} elseif ($success === false) {
    $output = ['error'=>'Error while uploading images. Contact the system administrator'];

    foreach ($paths as $file) {
        unlink($file);
    }
} else {
    $output = ['error'=>'No files were processed.'];
}

// return a json encoded response for plugin to process successfully
echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: try var_dump($_POST), could be the value is not in $_POST['album_id'];

Comment: Are you sure you pass a proper value for `$model->case_description` ? how do you pass this value to the form?

Comment: Yes.Is there a way to pass that model->case_description in yii2

Comment: Actually am not passing it to the form.Its alredy in the form (above the uploader in the example above).Am passing it from he form to the upload widget

Comment: But above the widget you have a form->field. This mean you use this like input for the case_description value?

Comment: I have posted an answer i hope is useful for you..

Comment: Yes I use it as input but the problem is the syntax used to pass the data to the extra part of the file uploader then to the controller. The answer hasn't worked yet, even after var_dump($_POST) I still get null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95744/discussion-between-geoffrey-mwangi-and-scaisedge).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due the problem with dinamic/variable assign to extraData i suggest a simple solution based on POST / submit method  (eventually set the proper action in your form)

```
    use kartik\widgets\FileInput

    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]); ?>

    <?= $form->field($model, 'case_description')->textArea();?>


        <?php   echo $form->field($evidence, 'path')->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
                        'options' => ['accept' => '*','multiple' => true,'name'=>'images'],
                        'pluginOptions' => [
                        'browseIcon' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-camera"></i> ',
                        'showPreview' => true,
                        'showCaption' => true,
                        'showRemove' => true,
                        'showUpload' => true,

                        'browseLabel' =>  'Insert Evidence',
                        'uploadUrl' => Url::to(['cases/upload']),
                        'maxFileCount' => 10,
                    ],              

                ]
        );

        echo Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Upload' : 'Update', [
            'class'=>$model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']
            );
        ActiveForm::end();
?>
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I pass that syntax to the upload extra data part.After adding the code as it is it returns an error of expecting [ ]

Comment: You must assign the proper field id.  You can retrive the id of the input field inspecting with firebugs or similar. But now is late we can continue tomorrow..

Comment: I get that but by default the upload extra data section is usuallu 'uploadextradata'=>[/define your data/], can you just explain how I can pass that function to that area. The problem is not getting the id but  using the function in the uploadextra area of the file input

Comment: I have uopdate the answer. If there are proble we continue tomorrow

Comment: Thanks awaiting your comment tomorrow since I still get the error even after using the updated code

Comment: His scais after passing it that way I still get an error of expecting ]

Comment: Maybe my problem is on the id declaration. Am I right declaring it as  $form->field($model, 'case_description',['id'=>'albumid'])->textArea(); in the form model since I always get the same error

Comment: The id of the fileld in $model->case_description is generated automatically by Yii2, you can see it inspecting the code /(CTRL +U with Firefox) or using firebugs and navigating to the html. However what's the error, show please...

Comment: After using the first solution and doing the var_dump($_POST) I get that the value of album_id is   "javascript: return $('#yourInputField_ID').val());",.Its like it treats the function  as a string.

Comment: After using the second solution I get no value of album_id

Comment: But what  value you use for #yourInputFieldID?

Comment: After checking it with firebug I found that the id value is   cases-case_description

Comment: And you use this in the second solution ?

Comment: plaese update the question and  show me the code you are using now..+

Comment: In the second solution where you are suggesting that I change the id to 1.Can you expound on where ill put the command that is cases-case_description=>1. where exactly on the view (that is the case_description) field

Comment: The motif is this. the widget assignement is due in server side when you don't know the vale for album_id, then i think is possible use an event and assigne the value assigned client side before the fileupload is done.  In server side configuration i simply set a default value for the extra data in this way  i can change the value with the runtime value. I hope this is clear for you.

Comment: I have update the answer with widget code i think (hope)  should work

Comment: According to the updated code can you guide me on how you do that considering that I know the value of album_id

Comment: I think you get the value fo album id form $model->case_description or not? the function  get whit jqery the value of this field and assign ii to the data  (extraData) album_id ( i think an attribute like data-album_id)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95796/discussion-between-scaisedge-and-geoffrey-mwangi).

Comment: @Thanks to you, I'm happy if this is useful for you

Comment: Hey scais am using your uploader but my controller upload always returns false I have provided the controller action in the question

Comment: Check what you obtain in $_FILES and in $_POST and evaluate your logic by these result...

Comment: I have checked and the files are passed through but they aren't being uploaded. The code(move_uploaded_file) is what doesn't upload where could the error be

Comment: The PHP manual say this function return false when the filename is checked to ensure that the file designated by filename and is not  a valid filename or the file can be moved for some reason.. Are you sure the filename generated is valid and/or can be mooved to destination?

Comment: I have checked the filename using var_dump($images['name']) and it seems to be valid but how do I check if I can be moved to destination

Comment: but for you ref. this is the related php man http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: Thanks for that I've found out the error to be  use of move_uploaded_file($images['name'], $target) instead it should be  move_uploaded_file($images['tmp_name'], $target)..Thanks for the reference

Comment: If you want you can post this as another question and i can post my answer... for rating and for help others

Comment: I ve posted   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33859816/error-in-uploading-files-in-yii2-move-upload-function, you deserve the rating man for the great help in my project