# Error in uploading files in yii2 move_upload function

Tags: php, yii2

Am doing multiple file upload in the controller but the file doesn't get uploaded
 controller code: for the upload

```
$images = $_FILES['evidence'];
$success = null;

$paths= ['uploads'];

// get file names
$filenames = $images['name'];


// loop and process files
for($i=0; $i < count($filenames); $i++){
//$ext = explode('.', basename($filenames[$i]));
$target = "uploads/cases/evidence".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . md5(uniqid()); //. "." . array_pop($ext);
if(move_uploaded_file($images['name'], $target)) {
    $success = true;
    $paths[] = $target;
} else {
    $success = false;

    break;
}

echo $success;
}
// check and process based on successful status 
if ($success === true) {
        $evidence = new Evidence();
        $evidence->case_ref=$id;
        $evidence->saved_on=date("Y-m-d");
        $evidence->save();

$output = [];
} elseif ($success === false) {
$output = ['error'=>'Error while uploading images. Contact the system administrator'];

foreach ($paths as $file) {
    unlink($file);
}
} else {
$output = ['error'=>'No files were processed.'];
}

//  return a json encoded response for plugin to process successfully
echo json_encode($output);
```

I have tried var_dump($images['name'] and everything seems okay the move file does not upload the file

Comment: I have posted the answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check what you obtain in $_FILES and in $_POST and evaluate your logic by these result...

The PHP manual say this function return false when the filename is checked to ensure that the file designated by filename and is not a valid filename or the file can be moved for some reason.. Are you sure the filename generated is valid and/or can be mooved to destination?

this is the related php man php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: Am also getting an error when saving the path to the database after the controller returns success the other parameters of evidence are not saved. After doing var_dump($evidence->save) I get a Boolean false on firebug

Comment: Please post this last question like another question... otherwise .. is not easy ...
navigate this layering of questions..

Comment: Not yet. Am trying to post another one but I have a question limit of 90 minutes

Comment: Well if you can post the question today... i can see it tomorrow morning.. comment me for remeber the question if not solved..

Comment: I posted at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33861358/saving-data-in-the-database-in-yii2-during-file-upload-action

Answer (score 1):

Have you added `enctype` attribute to form tag?

For example:

```
 <form action="demo_post_enctype.asp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: it has workec after checking the files at  php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php