# Saving data in the database in yii2 during file upload action

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have a upload controller where by am also performing saving other data to the database. The file uploading to the folder is okay but saving the other details in the table doesn't happen

```
controller code

$images = $_FILES['evidence'];
$success = null;

$paths= ['uploads'];

// get file names
$filenames = $images['name'];


// loop and process files
for($i=0; $i < count($filenames); $i++){
//$ext = explode('.', basename($filenames[$i]));
$target = "uploads/cases/evidence".DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . md5(uniqid()); //. "." . array_pop($ext);
if(move_uploaded_file($images['name'], $target)) {
    $success = true;
    $paths[] = $target;
} else {
    $success = false;

    break;
}

echo $success;
}
// check and process based on successful status 
if ($success === true) {
        $evidence = new Evidence();
        $evidence->case_ref=$id;
        $evidence->saved_on=date("Y-m-d");
        $evidence->save();

$output = [];
} elseif ($success === false) {
$output = ['error'=>'Error while uploading images. Contact the system administrator'];

foreach ($paths as $file) {
    unlink($file);
}
} else {
$output = ['error'=>'No files were processed.'];
}

//  return a json encoded response for plugin to process successfully
echo json_encode($output);
```

After doing `var_dump($evidence->save())` I get an error of Boolean `false`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have validation errors. Check `$errors` property

```
// check and process based on successful status 
if ($success === true) {
        $evidence = new Evidence();
        $evidence->case_ref=$id;
        $evidence->saved_on=date("Y-m-d");
        $retSave = $evidence->save();

        if($retSave == false)
        {
              var_dump($evidence->errors);
        }

$output = [];
}
....
```

Comment: Yap some  fields in the model were required but I hadn't supplied them with info